# iPhone SDK - Converting project from 2.1 to 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I just read in an online article that 2.2.1 does not support previous sdk. I wonder what that means? I just downloaded 2.2.1 and want to use updated/latest API's framework.

How can i convert my project so that it uses updated/latest API's/Frameworks in version 2.2.1? Are there any special steps required OR should i just 1.) delete 2.1 and 2.) install 2.2.1, and 3.) delete the Frameworks and reload them from iPhoneOS2.2.sdk directory instead, and that will do the magic.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe there are any obvious changes.  Download the current SDK, and open your project in the current XCode, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe to install. You don't have to "convert" anything. Your projects will continue to work. There are no new API's in 2.2.1. The documentation is a single page that tells you to refer to the 2.2 documentation.